# How to add colormap and rectangular boxes using matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, colormap

I'm trying to plot a precedence matrix plot from [bupar](https://www.bupar.net/precedence.html) in python.

[image: ![enter image description here]

So far I'm able to add the text and plot the categorical variables with the count.

```
def plot_precedence_matrix(data,colx,coly,cols,color=['grey','black'],ratio=10,font='Helvetica',save=False,save_name='Default'):
    

    df = data.copy()
    # Create a dict to encode the categeories into numbers (sorted)
    colx_codes=dict(zip(df[colx].sort_values().unique(),range(len(df[colx].unique()))))
    coly_codes=dict(zip(df[coly].sort_values(ascending=False).unique(),range(len(df[coly].unique()))))
    
    # Apply the encoding
    df[colx]=df[colx].apply(lambda x: colx_codes[x])
    df[coly]=df[coly].apply(lambda x: coly_codes[x])
    
    
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

    # Prepare the aspect of the plot
    # plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
    # plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
    plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=font
    
    plt.rcParams['xtick.color']=color[-1]
    plt.rcParams['ytick.color']=color[-1]
    # plt.box(False)

    
    # Plot all the lines for the background
    for num in range(len(coly_codes)):
        plt.hlines(num,-1,len(colx_codes),linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,color=color[num%2],alpha=0.1)
    for num in range(len(colx_codes)):
        plt.vlines(num,-1,len(coly_codes),linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,color=color[num%2],alpha=0.1)
        
    
    for x, y, tex in zip(df[colx], df[coly], df[colx]):
        t = plt.text(x, y, round(tex, 1), horizontalalignment='center', 
                     verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'color':'black',
                                                           'size':30})
    
    # Change the ticks numbers to categories and limit them
    plt.xticks(ticks=list(colx_codes.values()),labels=colx_codes.keys(),rotation=90)
    plt.yticks(ticks=list(coly_codes.values()),labels=coly_codes.keys())

    # Lighten borders
    plt.gca().spines["top"].set_alpha(0.1)
    plt.gca().spines["bottom"].set_alpha(0.1)
    plt.gca().spines["right"].set_alpha(0.1)
    plt.gca().spines["left"].set_alpha(0.1)


    # Save if wanted
    if save:
        plt.savefig(save_name+'.png')
```

Sample dataset

```
|         Antecedent |         Consequent | Count |
|-------------------:|-------------------:|-------|
|   register request | examine thoroughly |     1 |
| examine thoroughly |       check ticket |     2 |
|       check ticket |             decide |     6 |
|             decide |     reject request |     3 |
|   register request |       check ticket |     2 |
|       check ticket |   examine casually |     2 |
|   examine casually |             decide |     2 |
|             decide |   pay compensation |     3 |
|   register request |   examine casually |     3 |
|   examine casually |       check ticket |     4 |
|             decide | reinitiate request |     3 |
| reinitiate request | examine thoroughly |     1 |
|       check ticket | examine thoroughly |     1 |
| examine thoroughly |             decide |     1 |
| reinitiate request |       check ticket |     1 |
| reinitiate request |   examine casually |     1 |
```

```
colors=['darkorange','grey','darkblue']

#create the plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plot_precedence_matrix(df, 'Antecedent', 'Consequent', 'Count',color=colors,ratio=100, font='cursive')
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How to add the rectangular boxes with color scale using matplotlib? Can anybody shed some light on plotting the above plot with Python? I would be happy to receive any leads on it from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw colored rectangles at each of the positions. A colormap together with a norm could define the color.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

def plot_precedence_matrix(data, colx, coly, cols, color=['grey', 'black'], ratio=10, font='Helvetica',
                           save=False, save_name='Default'):
    df = data.copy()
    # Create a dict to encode the categeories into numbers (sorted)
    colx_codes = dict(zip(df[colx].sort_values().unique(), range(len(df[colx].unique()))))
    coly_codes = dict(zip(df[coly].sort_values(ascending=False).unique(), range(len(df[coly].unique()))))

    # Apply the encoding
    df[colx] = df[colx].apply(lambda x: colx_codes[x])
    df[coly] = df[coly].apply(lambda x: coly_codes[x])

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

    # Prepare the aspect of the plot
    plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = font
    plt.rcParams['xtick.color'] = color[-1]
    plt.rcParams['ytick.color'] = color[-1]

    # Plot the lines for the background
    for num in range(len(coly_codes)):
        ax.hlines(num, -1, len(colx_codes), linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, color=color[num % 2], alpha=0.1)
    for num in range(len(colx_codes)):
        ax.vlines(num, -1, len(coly_codes), linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, color=color[num % 2], alpha=0.1)

    cmap = ListedColormap(plt.get_cmap('Blues')(np.linspace(0.1, 1, 256)))  # skip too light colors
    norm = plt.Normalize(df[colx].min(), df[colx].max())
    for x, y, tex in zip(df[colx], df[coly], df[colx]):
        t = ax.text(x, y, round(tex, 1), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                    fontdict={'color': 'black' if norm(tex) < 0.6 else 'white', 'size': 30})
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x - .5, y - .5), 1, 1, color=cmap(norm(tex)), ec='white'))

    plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ax=ax)
    # Change the ticks numbers to categories and limit them
    ax.set_xticks(list(colx_codes.values()))
    ax.set_xticklabels(colx_codes.keys(), rotation=90, fontsize=14)
    ax.set_yticks(list(coly_codes.values()))
    ax.set_yticklabels(coly_codes.keys(), fontsize=14)

    # Lighten borders
    for spine in ax.spines:
        ax.spines[spine].set_alpha(0.1)

    plt.tight_layout()  # fit the labels into the figure
    if save:
        plt.savefig(save_name + '.png')

df_str = """
      register request | examine thoroughly |     1 
    examine thoroughly |       check ticket |     2 
          check ticket |             decide |     6 
                decide |     reject request |     3 
      register request |       check ticket |     2 
          check ticket |   examine casually |     2 
      examine casually |             decide |     2 
                decide |   pay compensation |     3 
      register request |   examine casually |     3 
      examine casually |       check ticket |     4 
                decide | reinitiate request |     3 
    reinitiate request | examine thoroughly |     1 
          check ticket | examine thoroughly |     1 
    examine thoroughly |             decide |     1 
    reinitiate request |       check ticket |     1 
    reinitiate request |   examine casually |     1 """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delimiter="\s*\|\s*", engine='python', names=['Antecedent', 'Consequent', 'Count'])
colors = ['darkorange', 'grey', 'darkblue']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plot_precedence_matrix(df, 'Antecedent', 'Consequent', 'Count', color=colors, ratio=100, font='cursive')
plt.show()
```

[image: adding colored boxes]

Comment: How to include the color scale in the plot?

Comment: A colorbar can be added via `plt.colorbar()` and a `ScalarMappable`. See updated example code.

Comment: Great, Thank You